# Prove Archimedean property does not imply axiom of completeness

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question from Steven Abbott and I do not get a hang out of it.

I have tried to go with proof by contradiction. But I can't come up with an obvious contradiction by assuming that Archimedean reaches axiom of completeness.

I have also tried contrapositive. But I can't prove how the contrary of axiom of completeness results in Archimedean property.

How should I approach this?

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ has the  Archimedean property, but $\mathbb Q$ is not complete

Comment: @Fred Thanks you. May I ask what does it mean by the "2" next to the flag? Is it upvote? If yes, then why can't I upvote your answer?